# Can view my website on localhost but not via an external IP

Tags: wamp

I'm trying to get my crappy desktop (with Windows XP) to be a web server. When I go to localhost it displays the website just fine, but when I go to the external IP on another computer it displays "mikrotik routeros 4.11 configuration page". I've forwarded port 80.

**Port forwarding (not sure if I did it right):**

[image]

**Microtik page that is displayed:**

[image]

I disabled my firewall but it's still not working.

Comment: how do you configure the site?

Comment: Have you put Wamp online?

Comment: The site is just an html page, and yes WAMP is online. I can go to localhost on the computer and it displays the website correctly.

Comment: How have you determine what your external IP is?  What ever IP you are going to, it doesn't seem to be your airstation, so I suspect you are hitting someone elses router.

Comment: Google and whatismyip.org both give me the same IP address. Is there a more reliable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've put WAMP online, and forwarded the port from router, and turned off remote management feature of the router, then it should be done by now. If it's not, then something else is on the way. If your global IP is forwarding you to Mikrotik page, then that means there is a mikrotik device on your network above your Router that's managing the traffic. maybe another router at the higher level. is it your Office network? or some shared network?

Comment: It's on my home network.

Comment: Are you aware of any Mikrotik device? Like a local router of your ISP or something?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to move the router's administration interface to a different port such as 8000 or 8080.

Comment: How do I do that? I have a Buffalo WHR-G54S.

Comment: Most likely, you can't, and so you can't use port 80 for the web server.

Comment: Better choice is **forward another WAN** port to local Apache. If port presence in URL isn't nice - redefine default http for domain (or host) in question with SRV